# unordered_map key issue "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type"

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have this:

```
unordered_map<string,string>* createDict(){

    unordered_map<string,string>* Dict= new unordered_map<string,string>();

    Dict["x"] = "a";
    Dict["y"] = "b";
    Dict["z"] = "c";

    return Dict;
}
```

and I get the error:

> expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

but this works when allocating on the stack. What is the easiest way to solve this? I really dont like having to create Pair objects to insert in to an unordered_map.

Comment: Why not have the function return an `unordered_map` instead of a pointer to one?

Comment: @us2012 I must be honest I was going to do that, but this is going to be a data member of a class.

Comment: @user997112 Why does being a class' data member make it necessary to dynamically allocate the map?

Comment: @Praetorian http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926689/c-when-to-allocate-on-heap-vs-stack

Comment: @user I'm wondering whether you might have some misconceptions about what it means to have an object member variable vs a pointer member variable in a class `A`. You *do not* need a pointer member variable just because you want to dynamically allocate objects of type `A`!

Comment: @user997112 Which reason are you pointing me to specifically? If it's stack size concern, the `unordered_map` itself will dynamically allocate memory for its nodes. If it's scope, then that is tied to the lifetime of the class instance that contains the map. In either case there's no need to `new` the map.

Answer (score 4):

`Dict` is a pointer to an `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>` but you are using it as if it is an object. You need to dereference the object appropriately, e.g., using

```
(*Dict)["x"] = "a";
Dict->operator[]("y") = "b";
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>& ref = *Dict;
ref["z"] = "c";
```

I'd prefer the first option or use

```
Dict->insert(std::make_pair("x", "a"));
```

Which has, however, slightly different semantics: if the key exists, it doesn't do anything while using the subscript operator and assignment would update the value.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the easiest way to solve this?

Use universal initialization and just return the `unordered_map` rather than a pointer:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> createDict(){
    return {{"x", "a"}, {"y", "b"}, {"z", "c"}};
}

int main() {
  auto xyz_dict = createDict();
}
```

Edit: Based on your comment that this data structure will be a member variable of some class, you could just initialize it in class:

```
struct A {
  using xyzDict = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;
  xyzDict xyz_dict{{"x", "a"}, {"y", "b"}, {"z", "c"}};   
};
```

If your compiler doesn't support this, then just initialize `xyz_dict` with `createDict()` in the constructor's member initialization list.