# C++ When to allocate on heap vs stack?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

Whilst asking another question (and also before) I was wondering how do I judge whether to create an object on the heap or keep it as an object on the stack? What should I ask myself about the object to make the correct allocation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put it on the heap if you have to, the stack if you can.

What kinds of things do you need to put on the heap?  Anything of varying length.  Any object that might need to be null.  Anything that's very large, lest you cause a stack overflow.

Comment: I agree with your statement, except I don't understand "Any object that might need to be null" .  What do you mean by "null"? Certainly not the traditional `NULL` or `nullptr`.

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer.

When it goes out of scope, do you want it to hang around and be able to use it?

Comment: It should be noted that it's also not a good idea to put gigantic objects on the stack even if they fulfill the other criteria. Especially no fun in c++ to overrun your stack limits..

Comment: @Voo Yes, but how often does that happen? Container classes allocate their memory dynamically, so I think it's safe to say that an object of size 1KB is (a) huge and (b) rare. Let's consider a call stack of depth 50 with 20 of these huge objects in every function's stack frame, and you're still only at a 1MB stack.

Comment: @voo - You can increase the stack size. You can also write code without the heap - as is required in a variety of safety critical industries,

Comment: And having to change an OS specific limitation to execute your code doesn't strike you as particularly bad design? Especially problematic if the limit depends on the input size.  @us2012 Rare situation? I'd really hope so, but what does that have to do with advice about what to do if you are in exactly one of those?

Comment: @voo - If the software has fixed inputs (as does a power station) and the software needs to run 24 x 7 from ages, avoiding memory fragmentation and the issues associated with dangling pointers then no. Welcome to the world of safety critical software#

Comment: @Ed So your answer relies on some extremely rare situation that most people won't run into and you don't see why mentioning everyday problems everybody else could run into would be important? "You don't have to worry about freeing memory" is also a valid advice in some situations, doesn't mean you should just position it as general advice.

Comment: @voo - If you can avoid the heap (i.e. use the stack) it is a worthwhile thing to think of. Saves a lot of hassle.

Comment: @Ed And the whole point is *when* you can avoid the heap and when not. Not mentioning a scenario where using the stack will end up badly in lots of situations because it works fine in some specific subcategory is not helpful.

Comment: @voo - Just pointing out the fact that you can completely avoid the heap. Therefore worth mentioning as the person may wish the software in question to be very robust

Answer (score 3):

Depends on *intended* lifetime of the object.

- If you want the object to be alive even after function returns, then HEAP, else STACK

If an object is placed in the HEAP, then it must be explicitly free()'ed or deleted by the programmer, once its usage is over; otherwise the program will be leaking memory.

Comment: Unless, of course, you return said object from the function. Then there are lots of cases in which it's good to return the object by value rather than a pointer to it.

Comment: Need to consider static data

Answer (score 2):

Stack memory is fast. It is fast because (a) there is no system overhead to allocate the memory - the allocation is done by simply moving the stack pointer in one instruction and (b) the memory in the stack is "hot" so it is already in cache.  Heap memory is slow because (a) it requires a lot of system work to look around and find a free chunk of memory and (b) is probably not in cache and will require evicting some data you might have wanted.

Stack memory doesn't get fragmented. It is possible that a heap eventually gets so fragmented, you can't allocate anything (even though ironically there is still enough unused memory!)

For long lived data and for large data (multi KB or more), you have to use a heap.

The danger of allocating a bigger stack is that it might hurt you if are running multiple threads. You have to size the stack for the "worst case" usage.  Each thread requires its own stack.  On a high core count machine (where you might have 200+ threads running), you may not want to arbitrarily increase the stack. The heap on the other hand does not need to be sized for "worst case" usage - it is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons to use the heap:

1- You want the data after the current scope.

2- You want to reserve large memory.

Other than that stay on stack.

Note: don't reserve a lot of memory on the stack, or you'll get a "Stack-overflow" ;)